# What is the function of two `io_service.run()`?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

In boost asio tutorial [timer5](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tuttimer5.html). I do not know the function of

`boost::thread t(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &io));` in main function.

Why should we invoke two `io_serice.run()`?

```
//
// timer.cpp
// ~~~~~~~~~
//
// Copyright (c) 2003-2013 Christopher M. Kohlhoff (chris at kohlhoff dot com)
//
// Distributed under the Boost Software License, Version 1.0. (See accompanying
// file LICENSE_1_0.txt or copy at http://www.boost.org/LICENSE_1_0.txt)
//

#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>

class printer
{
public:
  printer(boost::asio::io_service& io)
    : strand_(io),
      timer1_(io, boost::posix_time::seconds(1)),
      timer2_(io, boost::posix_time::seconds(1)),
      count_(0)
  {
    timer1_.async_wait(strand_.wrap(boost::bind(&printer::print1, this)));
    timer2_.async_wait(strand_.wrap(boost::bind(&printer::print2, this)));
  }

  ~printer()
  {
    std::cout << "Final count is " << count_ << "\n";
  }

  void print1()
  {
    if (count_ < 10)
    {
      std::cout << "Timer 1: " << count_ << "\n";
      ++count_;

      timer1_.expires_at(timer1_.expires_at() + boost::posix_time::seconds(1));
      timer1_.async_wait(strand_.wrap(boost::bind(&printer::print1, this)));
    }
  }

  void print2()
  {
    if (count_ < 10)
    {
      std::cout << "Timer 2: " << count_ << "\n";
      ++count_;

      timer2_.expires_at(timer2_.expires_at() + boost::posix_time::seconds(1));
      timer2_.async_wait(strand_.wrap(boost::bind(&printer::print2, this)));
    }
  }

private:
  boost::asio::strand strand_;
  boost::asio::deadline_timer timer1_;
  boost::asio::deadline_timer timer2_;
  int count_;
};

int main()
{
  boost::asio::io_service io;
  printer p(io);
  boost::thread t(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &io));
  io.run();
  t.join();

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That example is showing how to use a thread pool (in this case, comprised by two threads). You may need a pool if you want more than one async handler to execute at the same time.

To quote the page you linked:

> If you find yourself running into these limitations, an alternative approach is to have a pool of threads calling io_service::run()

To submit a thread to the asio thread pool, you execute `io_service::run` on that thread. This example submits two threads: the boost::thread `t` and the main thread.

Comment: It use 2 thread to demonstrate that strand make sure handler1 and hander2 excuted one by one but simultaneously. If we use one thread, handler will sure be excuted one by one no matter we use `strand` or not.

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial demonstrates how to concurrently execute handlers by having a pool of threads invoking [`io_service::run()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/run.html).  However, the tutorial diminishes demonstrating this by dispatching both asynchronous call chains through the same [`strand`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service__strand/wrap.html), where in the handlers are guaranteed to not run concurrently.

Nevertheless, the documentation suggests having a pool of threads calling `io_service::run()` if the application experiences:

> - Poor responsiveness when handlers can take a long time to complete.
> - An inability to scale on multiprocessor systems.